# How to change the color of shape set in imageview

Tags: android

Now problem starts with just setting the color of a shape.
I created one rectangle shape in `drawable` and set it to `ImageView` like this

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0.15" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
       <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_priority"
        android:src="@drawable/case_priority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

My case_priority.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#009600" />
  <size android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

now I need to change the color of this shape. Actually this color is coming from web service, and I need to change it.
So My **Question** is: How can we change color of this shape programmatically. and set it to imageview. 
I have gone through few examples in stackoverflow but I am not able to change it to image view.Please Help!!!!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

May be I was not clear in my question, So Just a refinement to question . Actually I have a ImageView  where I set a source which is actually a drawable. By default its green as in my code shown above. Now web service returns the color of this image view which needs to be changed accordingly , so I can't change it from xml during runtime so I need to change it from java file. Since I am using shape and image view, .setBackground() won't help much here. So What can be the probable solution for this. Thanks for answer and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Yes I know I need to go by your way only, but don't know how to proceed further

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanx for all the answers.It helped me getting to answer.

In My layout I changed `android:src="" to android:background="@drawable/case_priority"`
And in my java file I n=included this code:->

```
        Resources res = getResources();
        final Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.case_priority);
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_priority);
        img.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

that's it. Hope it will someone.

Comment: There's an easier way to approach this if you assign the shape to the ``ImageView``'s ``src`` attribute. See my answer.

Comment: @Black Devil, Perfect Solution. It's working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable.

Instead of creating the `Shape` in code you can use `inflate` to inflate your XML if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but being a novice may I ask u for some tutorial/article help , which elobrate your answer

Answer (score 2):

add this to image view

```
android:background="#152" // or some other color code
```

**Edit 1 :**
to do it with code do this

```
ImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("red")); // Or any color code like #000 , #987
```

**Edit 2:**

```
ImageView Imgs = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_priority);

Imgs.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ColorCode"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, but I have the color and already have set it in shape. But I need to change it programmatically, through java file.

Comment: Yes sir, I did that but now my image view is missing.

Comment: so you should change the color of your drawable see where the solid is setting the color

Comment: use shapedrawable it have color attribute in which u can use shapeDrawable.setColor(value)

Comment: sure, but when I am using this with imageview, its giving cast exception, Can u give some code snippet for your view.

Comment: i saw this link may it help you too http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html

Comment: android:background="#152" is not helpful as it does not change the color of the shape but the ImageView's background.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg You are right and also this is not the direct answer of the question check the comments for more explanations i delivered

Answer (score 2):

IimageView.setBackgroundColor("#152");

Answer (score 1):

All solutions suggest to use the ImageView's background. I think this is not the desired solution. The question already reflects what an intuitive approach would be: Applying the shape to the `src` attribute. In order to then change the shape's color programmatically you would do:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) priorityImageView.getDrawable();
drawable.setColor(Color.RED);
```

given that the shape is assigned as in the original question:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv_priority"
    android:src="@drawable/case_priority"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This also brings the advantage that you can set the ImageView's background separately from its content.

Comment: This works! Much more neat and clean than the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As [Lars Blumberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20495910/543875) I also did not want to change the background, so I applied the following to code to my Image, since I did not have a GradientDrawable:

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```